# How do I combine CountIf with If

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, countif

To generate some statistics with a google form result I need to count all reponse "yes" only on column which contain "moteur"

Can I combine CountIf twice ? Or Can I use countIf in a If ?

Here the table result :
[image]

I use this, but the result is not good :
=COUNTIF(C1;"moteur";COUNTIF(C3;"oui"))

I've tried a lot of different approaches with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*REGEXMATCH(C:D; "moteur|oui")))
```